# Filter on Pivot Tables using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have put a filter on the Pivot Table. I have written a code that filters (removes) the entries with a value less than 0. I want to remove data entries with "0" and blanks too. Below is my code that filters entries that start with "-" sign. Please suggest how I can filter "0" and blanks.

```
Dim i As Integer
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Short Quantity")
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
           If Left(.PivotItems(i), Len("-")) = "-" Then
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Else
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        End If

    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Chetan: Did either of the below answers solve your question? If so, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you only want positive numbers to show in the Pivot? If you put the 'Short Quantity' field into the pivot as a Values field as well as a row field, then you can put a Values filter on the field to suppress anything below zero, which also suppresses blanks:

Before:

[image]

Applying VALUES filter:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim i As Integer
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Short Quantity")
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        If Left(.PivotItems(i), Len("-")) = "-" Or _
                .PivotItems(i) = "(blank)" Or _
                .PivotItems(i) = 0 Then
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Else
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        End If

    Next i
End With
```

Comment: It removed all 0 and negative entries, however, the blanks are not filtered. Thank you.

Comment: @ChetanChimate When you say "blanks", are they in the pivot table as `(blank)` or are there are literal blank spaces like `" "`?